# Type annotation of Hibernate is not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, nhibernate-mapping

I want to convert UUID value from bytes to string by using @Type annotation as:
`@Type(type="uuid-char")` but I am getting the error: The attribute type is undefined for the annotation type Type.

Import: `import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;`
Code:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(40)")
    @Type(type="uuid-char")
    @JsonIgnore
    private UUID id;
```

I also searched it here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2794 but it had the same syntax I was using. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

Try use `@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.VARCHAR)` instead.

After updating to Spring Boot 3.0.0 we had the same problem. Using `@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.VARCHAR)` instead. I tried it out with PSQL.

Comment: This doesn't work for JSON. I'm getting an exception " 'Basic' attribute type should not be use" when trying to map an object to JSON

Answer (score 0):

Tried a workaround to save the *UUID* string to the database. I changed the data type of the `id` field from *UUID* to *String* and it worked fine.

Updated entity class definition:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
@Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(40)")
@JsonIgnore
private String id;
```